# Siri: Is it possible to show customized UI for workout domain, instead of opening the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Can we show the response in SIRI window itself for workout domain, like we show for the message, payment, ride domain?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, no. Looking at the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/instartworkoutintentresponsecode) of `INStartWorkoutIntentResponseCode`, you can see that it has no `success` case, which is required to show an IntentUI Extension after your Intent Handler returned. At the moment, you can only start the workout from Siri, but if it was successful, you have to open your app. However, in iOS11, the `success` response code is going to implemented, so in iOS11 what you want to achieve should be possible.